# Trying to get value out of text view in list view click event in android

Tags: java, android, events, listview, listviewitem

I have a click event hooked up to my listview as shown.

```
int[] GenusListIDs = { R.id.txt_ID, R.id.txt_Genus, R.id.txt_Count };
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.genusitem, cursor_genuslist, service.GenusListColumns, GenusListIDs);

        ListView list_Genus = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_Genus);
        list_Genus.setAdapter(adapter);
        list_Genus.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                try
                {
                    Log.println(1, "ItemClick", view.toString());
                    TextView tv = (TextView)view;
                    String genus = (String) tv.getText();
                    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Cat_Species.class);//new Intent(this, Total.class);
                    /*view
                    i.putExtra("id", id);*/
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.println(1, "item-click-event", ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
```

I need to pass a string param to the new intent based on which listitem they clicked on.  The value I want to pass is in the listitem called txt_Genus.  How do I get that value out of the listitem to pass to the intent?  Don't pay attention to my experiments please haha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it.

```
TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_Genius);
String genus = tv.getText().toString();
```

Then put it into the intent extras, I think you already know this bit.

```
i.putExtra("genius", genius);
```

Edit;

In your new activity you would access the intent and get the extras bundle.  You can then access anything you placed in the intent on your previous activity  like below;

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String genius = extras.getString("genius");
// pop some toast to show the value of genius - not required but shows it works :) 
Toast.makeText(this, "Genius value: " + genius, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  Just what I needed.  Now how do I get that value in the onCreate method on my new activity?

Comment: Updated answer for you.

Damon