# Making Object from getItem() and accessing the fields

Tags: java, android

I have a list listview in my code that contains 2 buttons and 2 TextViews. I want to access the text of each textView by Clicking on buttons. here is the code of the adapter...

```
public class TracksAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    public TracksAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int      resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final TracksAdapter proxy = this;
        final View trackView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        Button dl = (Button) trackView.findViewById(R.id.dl);
        dl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Do something with data : proxy.getItem(position)
                TextView tv = (TextView) trackView.findViewById(R.id.track);
                String track = tv.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , track , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        });

        Button play = (Button) trackView.findViewById(R.id.play);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Do something with data : proxy.getItem(position)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , String.valueOf(proxy.getItem(position)).indexOf("file=") , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        });

        return trackView;
    }
}
```

the result of `proxy.getItem(position)` is something like `{id=4 , name=foo , track=fofoo}`

what should I do to access 'foo' ????

Comment: `proxy.getItem(position).name`

Comment: I've tried it but name is not specified. It's not correct.

Comment: are you referring to TracksAdapter of `iosched`? If so, then there is no field named `name` in that class. Refer to its API. If it is your own class, post its code.

Comment: I edited the code. it extends SimpleAdapter

Comment: have to check the type of the instance of the object, and then cast it to the class you want to retrieve data.
Then you can access myobject.name

Comment: SimpleAdapter's getItem returns `Object` type. So the answer to your question `how to access foo` is that you can't. You can only access Object class members with it. I believe, you are doing something inherently wrong here. You should probably see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273834/trying-to-get-value-out-of-text-view-in-list-view-click-event-in-android
basically, you need to traverse through your button to the parent and then lookup the TextView by Id and then get its text

Answer (score 0):

Try his code to get the text from onClick:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.your_textView_position_id_from_xml);
String s = tv.getText().toString();
```

Comment: It didnt work for all the buttons! I finally had to parse that string ({id=4 , name=foo , track=fofoo}) to get the value of name!